# CSS box-shadow works in IE9+ but does not print?

Tags: css

I was trying to use box-shadow as a workaround for background colors not printing by default ... looks like this workaround works in Chrome and Safari but not in IE8/9/10. Just wanted to confirm with others that this was the case.

Here's the code:

```
@media print {

    #fusioncolor {
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    #fusioncolor .bg1 {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #AFD8F8;
    }

    #fusioncolor .bg2 {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #F6BD0F;
    }

    #fusioncolor .bg3 {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #8BBA00;
    }

    #fusioncolor .bg4 {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #FF8E46;
    }

}


<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" id="fusioncolor">

                <tr style="cursor: pointer" onClick="showOpens(true)" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E8F2FE'" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''">
                    <td align="right" class="big fgGrey l6e">opened</td>
                    <td width="50px" class="big box gl8t bg1" id="id-opened" turntitle="Opens">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" id="id-openedpct"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="cursor: pointer" onClick="showBounces()" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E8F2FE'" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''">
                    <td align="right" class="big fgGrey l6e">bounced</td>
                    <td class="big box gl8t bg2" id="id-bounced"    title="Bounces">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" id="id-bouncedpct"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="cursor: pointer" onClick="showNoOpens()" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E8F2FE'" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''">
                    <td align="right" class="big fgGrey nobr l6e">did not open</td>
                    <td class="gl8t big box bg3" id="id-notopened"  title="No Opens / No Responses">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" id="id-notopenedpct"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="cursor: pointer" onClick="clicksDrillDown('', $('id-clicked').innerHTML.replace(/,/g,''), true)" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#E8F2FE'" onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''">
                    <td align="right" class="big fgGrey l6e">clicked</td>
                    <td class="big box gl8t bg4" id="id-clicked"    title="Unique Clicks">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" id="id-clickedpct"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

And here's a link to a JSFiddle without the CSS print media query: http://jsfiddle.net/RNKJN/

Comment: Well do they get printed if you set IE to print backgrounds? If so, then that’s your answer right there.

Comment: Hey CBroe, thanks I should have thought to do that. Yes, IE9 does print box-shadows when I enable background colors to print. So I guess this suggests that IE considers box-shadows in the category of background color whereas Chrome and Firefox do not.

Answer (score 1):

IE Wont support box shadow except **ie9+**

if you give prefix `-ms` it can work in latest IE version

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #F6BD0F;

-ms-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px #F6BD0F;
```

Comment: Seems like it is supported in IE9+ ... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: W3Schools says so, it must be true! :P

Comment: Haha Agony, here is a more trusted source then ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow